# How to exclude property from XML Binding

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am trying to marshal a class that looks like the following using JAXB

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType(propOrder = {"first", "last"})
public class Person
{
    private String first;
    private String last;
    public String getFirst(){
        return first;
    }
    public void setFirst(String first){
        this.first = first;
    }
    public String getLast(){
        return last;
    }
    public void setLast(String last){
        this.first = last;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return this.first + this.last;
    }
}
```

When I try to get the JaxbContext using:

```
JAXBContext.newInstance(Person.class);
```

I get the following exception:

```
com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 182 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Property name is present but not specified in @XmlType.propOrder
this problem is related to the following location:
    at public java.lang.String myPackage.Person.getName()
    at myPackage.Person
```

It is very similar to the problem posted here:

https://www.java.net//node/702784

Where the solution was to add

```
 @XmlTransient
```

to the offending method. However, I am unable to edit the java classes to update the annotations.

Any ideas how to move past this?

---

I ended up using a library called JAXBIntroductions which allowed me to temporarily introduce annotations at runtime, thus alleviating the problem without causing too much overhead.
Thanks to everyone who had a look

---

Comment: Do you know which version of the JAXB RI you are using?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't edit them, why don't create a new subclass of Person and override the method to add the @XmlTransient annotation?